# Order posts by custom column using pre_get_posts

Tags: wp-query, order, pre-get-posts

Is it possible to sort posts by custom column in wp_posts table (in this case, 'fav_count' column) using pre_get_posts filter? If not, is there any other way to do this before the main query is run, without modifying WP core files?

Comment: Is there a reason you have a custom column instead of using post meta data?

Comment: Yes - optimization, avoiding JOINs. It's a pretty big website with lots of visitors and over 300.000 posts.

Answer (score -1):

I found out the answer myself.

There are other filters that let you adjust the query before it's run:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_clauses

> The posts_clauses filter runs before the query gets executed and is essentially the sum of all filters that run immediately before it.

Apart from posts_clauses, there are several more precise filters that modify only a single specific clause:

> - posts_where_paged
> - posts_groupby
> - posts_join_paged
> - posts_orderby
> - posts_distinct
> - post_limits
> - posts_fields

So in my case, all I had to do was to use **posts_orderby** filter.